# Random exitcode 1 after refreshing, using php proc_open to execute node & npm

Tags: php, node.js, wamp, exit-code, proc-open

I really can't figure this one out.

What could be causing my Wamp localhost to occasionally throw an error (exitcode 1) when I refresh the page?

Same script, same execution... but for some reason every now and then I get an `exitcode 1` AND my test with `npm list` thinks its *current working directory* is in the Apache installation folder (I seriously have no idea where it got that from...)

This issue is a little hard to explain in words, so here's a GifCam capture:

**=====================================================**

[image]

**=====================================================**

I've tried a bunch of different things to isolate where the issue could be:

- Tried different browser (Firefox, Chrome and IE 11).
- Installing new version of Wamp (was on a 32-bit Wamp, now Wamp64).
- Switching from PHP 5.6.16 to PHP 7.0.0.
- Trying to close all `proc_open` pipes after it's called.

Some notes / observations:

- Running on Windows 7 64bit (bootcamped).
- Apache installation is on C: drive (a HDD).
- PHP project is running on W: drive (an SSD).
- Apache's `/www/` folder contains a **symbolic link**, pointing to `W:\_WWW\`.
- NodeJS is installed on the C: drive.
- The error seems to happen most often after I make a modification to the PHP script or node js script. After a few refreshes it seems to operate normally (on a more regular basis).

I'm leaning towards there's a chance it's caused by the symbolic link, but I've been searching for known similar issues on the web and nothing seems to come close to this.

Here's a code example:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>CMS</title>
</head>

<body>
<a href='?node=npm&node_args=list'>Click to run "npm list"</a><br/>
<pre>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['node'])) die();
function trace($msg) { echo "$msg\n"; }
$errorFile = "./.node-errors.txt";
$descriptorspec = [
    0 => ["pipe", "r"],  // stdin is a pipe that the child will read from
    1 => ["pipe", "w"],  // stdout is a pipe that the child will write to
    2 => ["file", $errorFile, "a"] // stderr is a file to write to
];
$nodeCommand = $_GET['node'];;
if(isset($_GET['node_args'])) {
    trace("NodeJS Args: " . $_GET['node_args'] . "\n\n");
    $nodeArgs = $_GET['node_args'];
} else {
    $nodeArgs = '';
}
//??? test
//$nodeCommand $nodeArgs
$process = proc_open("npm list", $descriptorspec, $pipes, getcwd());
if (is_resource($process)) {
    echo stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[1]);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    //fclose()
    // It is important that you close any pipes before calling
    // proc_close in order to avoid a deadlock
    $return_value = proc_close($process);
    if ($return_value !== 0) {
        trace("ERROR: command returned $return_value");
        echo file_get_contents($errorFile);
        //file_put_contents($errorFile, ''); //Clear the error
    } else {
        trace("===============================\nCompleted server-side command.");
    }
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

UPDATE:

In case it's worth mentioning - the project where I'm running this is version controlled (Git), and usually I have the Github desktop client open. Maybe its causing issues while monitoring for file changes? Going to try to keep it closed tomorrow...

Comment: I cannot suggest a positive solution. But I would start by de-complicating things and putting everything on the same drive

Comment: yeah definitely worth a shot. In fact, I noticed some strange file access behaviors even before I messed around with NodeJS via PHP. I was using parse_ini_file and occasionally it wouldn't find the ini file (if I recall correctly). I may be able to simplify the code as well.

Comment: After moving the project files even only one symlink deep (instead of 2) the issue seems to be non-existent! So there's definitely something going on with depth of symlinks access, not sure how to access any informative logs though to prove it.